# Visual Basic error exception of type and data mismatch

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to populate the combobox into MS Access database and display the values into a textbox the combobox can read the ID into the database but when I choose the id to display data into a textbox I encounter this error

"A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

so far here is my code.

```
Public Class List_of_patient
    Sub fillcombo()
        strsql = "select * from ptInfo"
        Dim acscmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        acscmd.CommandText = strsql
        acscmd.Connection = acsconn
        acsdr = acscmd.ExecuteReader
        While (acsdr.Read())
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(acsdr("PaintNo"))
        End While

        acscmd.Dispose()
        acsdr.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub List_of_patient_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Module1.connect()
        Me.fillcombo()

    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        strsql = "select * from ptInfo where PaintNo = '" & ComboBox1.Text & "'"
        Dim acscmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        acscmd.CommandText = strsql
        acscmd.Connection = acsconn
        acsdr = acscmd.ExecuteReader

        If (acsdr.Read() = True) Then
            TextBox4.Text = (acsdr("diag"))
            TextBox3.Text = (acsdr("Pname"))

        End If
        acscmd.Dispose()
        acsdr.Close()

    End Sub



End Class
```

and here's my  module

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Module Module1
    Public acsconn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Public acsdr As OleDbDataReader
    Public strsql As String

    Sub connect()
        acsconn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0; data source=|datadirectory|patient.accdb"
        acsconn.Open()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Please help me. thanks in advance :)

Comment: What's the type of <PaintNo> field?

Comment: it's a primary autonumber long int

Comment: you need to cast the data or convert it from int to string meaning 
`TextBox4.Text = (acsdr("diag"))` if the field contains an integer value then try something like this `TextBox4.Text = (string)acsdr("diag")` or `TextBox4.Text = acsdr("diag").ToString()` for fields that are integer type you can not populate a textbox with an Integer without converting or casting it to a string.. also try to implement the usage of Parameterized query's when doing Sql

Comment: You are wide open to SQL Injection please consider [OleDbParameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter.aspx) instead of building the sql statement like that. Also, you say `PaintNo` is long int, but you look for it with `"... WHERE PaintNo='someValue'"`. The single quotes say "interpret the value as string". So you're comparing a long int with text, which is most likely where the `Data type mismatch` comes from.

Comment: I have tried that but it's still giving me the same error sir. :(

Comment: Thankyou mr corak I get what you mean. now it works fine thanks to all of you. god bless!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
                strsql = "select * from ptInfo where PaintNo = " & CLng(ComboBox1.Text) 
                Dim acscmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
                acscmd.CommandText = strsql
                acscmd.Connection = acsconn
                acsdr = acscmd.ExecuteReader

                If (acsdr.Read() = True) Then
                    TextBox4.Text = (acsdr("diag"))
                    TextBox3.Text = (acsdr("Pname"))

                End If
                acscmd.Dispose()
                acsdr.Close()

            End Sub
```